# Collaborative Choose-Your-Own-Adventure system... how do i build it?

Tags: joomla, wiki, mediawiki, collaboration

I've had this idea bouncing around in my head, and I decided I'm going to do it and learn a little in the process.

Okay, if you don't mind, I'm going to pitch my website project to you.
It is based on collaboration, so I thought MediaWiki would be the best place to start, but I don't know where to go from here. I also checked out SemanticMediaWiki and SemanticForms, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

My project is a site revolving around Multiple Choice Adventures. There are already sites that do this, like http://editthis.info/choose_your_own_adventure/Main_Page but I aim to have it entirely user friendly.
On that site, users must employ wiki markup effectively and set up the links manually. That's functional and effective, but I want it to be totally user friendly.
I want the links and content submission to be a fluid process with no worrying about wiki markup.

Here's what I want:

A user creates a top level page. A new story. (Possibly a category?) He titles it "Knights and Princesses".
He is asked to fill in the story text. He writes, "You are a handsome knight with a brand new sword. A dragon is swooping towards you."
He saves the page.
The page now contains the title, the story text, and a link/button saying "Add a new story branch".

A second user comes along. He reads this page, and clicks "Add a new story branch".
He is prompted to fill in a form. Absolutely no technical markup or manual editing.
He fills in his chosen title "Run Away".
He fills in his story text "The dragon chases you as you flee, but you concentrate on running as fast as you can. You notice a rabbit hopping along side you."
He saves the page.

Two things happen.
1: The previous page is automatically updated. Above the link "Add a new story branch" a new link appears, titled "Run Away". This new button links to the new page.
2: The new page is published with the title, the story text, and also a link/button saying "Add a new story branch".
Anyone can come along, click that button, write a new page, and the links will be added seamlessly. No need for messing with editing the page and adding wiki markup or URLs.

In addition, I hope to have the ability to categorize stories by adult content,and have a method to police and filter that.
I hope to have the ability for the original authors of a new story to define what the permissions will be, i.e. "Authorized users only", "anyone can edit", "only registered users".
I hope to have the ability for only original authors to lock certain pages from being edited.
I hope to have the ability for authors to make stories private for a select group of users.
I hope to enable users to edit story text without seeing nasty code and markup.

Am I dreaming here, or is this possible with MediaWiki? I am only experienced in Joomla and MediaWiki.
Do I need to learn a web framework? (Rails, Django, Pylons, etc) Where do I start? Are there solutions that are already geared toward my project?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

This definitely sounds doable. Did you know that one of the original iterations of Mahalo.com was built on mediawiki? Mediawiki is very flexible software, and with a little bit of technical know-how and time you will have no problem accomplishing this.

In fact, I bet if you made it an open source project others would help you.

Comment: How would I go about making it an open source project on a live server without sacrificing security? Thanks.

Comment: In the same way that wikipedia does. One installed version of the software that displays your content, then make the source code available on some other site. Changes to the code don't have to go live onto your server until you check them in.

Answer (score 1):

If you want heavy access control (access control lists, extra privileges for the creator of the pages etc.) then MediaWiki is not a good match.

If you want easy-to-use WYSIWYG editing which does not hinder collaboration, then it is again not a good match (though it is [coming along](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Visual_editor), and I am not sure there *is* a good match currently).

For the automatic creation of links, I think Semantic MediaWiki is the right tool. You need to define a precedes-follows relationship, use semantic forms or something similar to create new pages which reference the current page as predecessor, and list the names of following pages on the bottom of each page.

Comment: >[You need to define a precedes-follows relationship, use semantic forms or something similar to create new pages which reference the current page as predecessor]     

Yep. I figured that much out, but I just don't know how to do it.